# Mailing list subscriptions in CiviCRM on Wordpress with smart groups

Tags: subscribe

I have a number of Smart Groups designated as mailing lists in CiviCRM on Wordpress. I would like to list these on the subscription page and have set the visibility for these to "Expose Publicly." Yet, when I go to the subscription page, it says "There are no public mailing list groups to display." What can I do to get these groups to display on the subscription page?

Comment: I would expect that if a Smart Group is set as both Mailing List and Public Pages, then yes these would show on the Subscription page for people with permission to see that page.

Comment: or have them show as options within a Profile by using the Groups field